# What page is loaded in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this command : `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );` to load html page's content into div.
My question is how to know what I entered after I enterd it. A function that return the html page that is already inside the div.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to know what I entered after I enterd it.

Comment: I mean a function that can get the loaded page - like
$("#result").getloadedPage

Comment: Do you mean a function callback like `.done()`?

Comment: i don't understand your question please explain your question and problem

Comment: I'm loading different html pages into div. and I dont want to load html page to the div if i have already loaded it. so i want to know what is the html page that is already inside div

Comment: Just keep track of that in a javascript variable

Comment: But everytime the javascript is finished the variable resets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store in a variable the currently loaded page (`currentPage`) and compare the page you load with the value of this variable:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="load('test1.html')" value="Load">
<script>
    var currentPage;
    function load(page) {
        if ( currentPage != page ) {
            $("#result").load(page, function () {
                currentPage = page;
            });
        }
        else console.log('already loaded');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to access the contents of that page after it is loaded, You can use the callback of the function load.

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
   alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

The callback is added as the second parameter one function and work within when it is charged.

You can also receive parameters in the callback.

Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

Full documentation have it here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: lets say i loaded test.html page's content. and now i want to load test2.html's content. Before that i want to know if that is the page that is already loaded inot the div